# Should "that of" pronoun be used after "as well as" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Nearby is the jousting armor of Emperor Ferdinand as well as England’s Earl of Pembroke.

**Or is this correct:**

Nearby is the jousting armor of Emperor Ferdinand as well as **that of** England’s Earl of Pembroke.

Comment: Your original says that two things are nearby: a suit of armor and an Earl.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate the possessive somehow. There are two common ways to do this English:

1. Genitive: *the Earl of Pembroke's*
2. Prepostion: *of the Earl of Pembroke*

You would say

*Nearby is the jousting armor of Emperor Ferdinand as well as the Earl of Pembroke's.*

But once you add *Englands's* that would become too complicated. In English, and in other languages, a preposition is the if-all-else-fails possessive construction so that is why you use *that of* here.